# T-Shirt reward requirements

Tags: relays

I am currently running a Tor relay (guard) to help the Tor network. After a while I realised that I can actually get an T-Shirt for running an relay more than two months. ([link](https://2019.www.torproject.org/getinvolved/tshirt.html))

Two questions about this:

1. Does Tor still do this? (Do they send T-shirts for running a relay)
2. "Two months" means two months of uptime? Or it does mean two months since appearing? (But overall the uptime is good)

Answer (score 1):

Email tshirt@torproject.org and ask directly. While people from the Tor Project often look at stackexchange it's always best to just ask directly if there is a contact method.

With that said, the page does not mention an expiration date though I can tell you there was a contest last month for creating bridges that has expired. Your best option really is to ask.

Comment: Thanks! I've sent an EMail to tshirt@torproject.org. I will update the question if they answer me.

Answer (score 1):

I got a t-shirt last month :) So to answer your first question, yes I believe they still do it. Regarding your second question I'm fairly certain, based on a previous email conversation I had with them, that you need to keep up the speed for the duration. I could be wrong however because their manual also recommends a shorter uptime (in days) if that means a higher bandwidth on your relay, versus uptime of an entire month at the cost of bandwidth.

As a relay operator I, too, thank you for joining :)

I made a guide on how to run a relay as a docker container by the way, if you're interested.

Comment: Hello! That's good that they are still doing this. Another question from you: How did you verify that you are the admin and owner of the server?

Comment: I don’t remember if I did anything except send the email from the same IP along with the details the request (see their website).